# No "android resource directory" option on right clicking res folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm an iOS developer, and I'm expanding my skill set by working through the recommended Udacity tutorials for Android development.

In the "Add a Menu" tutorial in "Developing Android Apps", in order to create a new XML file for menus, it states:

"right click the res directory, select 'Android  Resource Directory'". This is followed by a number of other points to correctly set up a menu xml file.

On my system, when I right click on the res directory, I have no option for "Android Resource Directory". I've uploaded a screen grab of what I get:

[image]

compared to the tutorial:

[image]

I've tried just creating a standard directory, and then right clicking and making a new xml file within it, but it doesn't seem to be working, as the XML file won't even open when I double click on it. I'm guessing it also won't be setup correctly, and I'm not sure how to do that manually.

I also tried the "Resource Bundle" option, but it didn't seem to give similar options as to what the tutorial says is to be expected.

I've had a look in the Udacity forums, and didn't see anything there on this. They also didn't seem to be frequented much, so I thought asking here was a better idea.

I'm also guessing Gradle sync error is not causing this, I haven't looked into the cause of that yet, I think perhaps because of my Core2 processor...

My guess is it's to do with my newer version of Android Studio, but I've been unable to find any info on this.

Thanks for any pointers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your gradle project files are **not synced properly**. As it is in screenshot you shared. You need to make sure gradle syncs successful so android studio will provide those context menu options properly for specific directory
Here - Resource directory

Comment: Ah, so it is that? I was going to worry about that part next :) I'll look into it

Comment: I think this might be one of the reason. Try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks. Curiously I just tried opening terminal, and it's failing to open. restart needed..

Comment: I've just restarted, and it recommended updating Gradle, which is weird, as I'm pretty sure I did that yesterday. And I also restarted this morning without it suggesting anything. I said OK, and It's still working through it..

Comment: HA! its worked! I can't believe I posted something that required "have you tried turning it off and back on again" as a solution. LOL, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Click on Build->Clean Project and then file-> sync project with gradle file

Comment: can you please share the build logs so i can identify that what is actually going wrong

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I seem to have it working now. Embarrassingly, it required turning it off and turning it on again...

Answer (score 0):

Try the menu New/Folder/Font folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).